# 1970s TV show where children rule

Tags: story-identification, tv

What is the title for this TV series that I only very vaguely remember from my pre-school years:

- It was on in the UK, probably 1975 or 1976.
- It was a live action show, and was probably a series rather than a single show or film.
- It was similar in tone to *The Tomorrow People*, but it wasn't that.
- The characters were all children, and they all wore the same uniform, possibly yellow. This is why I recall it as sci-fi. Actually there was one episode where an adult appears but he was subdued by the children and kept prisoner.
- My recollection is that the filming location was in some kind of quarry.

I apologise for the lack of details but it was a long time ago and I was really young. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: 1970s shows were always filmed in a quarry.

Comment: @Valorum Exactly! I'll be amazed if anyone can solve this - it's been bugging me for literally three decades

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum Updated to include my recollection of the show's tone.

Comment: I shall be interested to see if you get any reply, because I was 12 at the time and watching any UK children’s SF that I could find, and yet it rings no bells with me.

Comment: @Mike Scott I am relying on it ringing a bell with someone! I can trace my own interest in SF back to seeing this show at such an early age, but I can't find any record of its existence.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TeenageWasteland

Comment: @MikeScott perhaps you saw this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150944/id-a-british-kids-series-involving-a-celtic-hammer

Comment: Yellow-uniformed kids, *one* scene in a quarry and a world ruled by children might point at *Logan's Run*. If that were the case, you should remember more than that, though; and I believe it was never a series.

Comment: @LSerni, there was a *Logan's Run* series but I don't know how close it was to the movie or whether it includes the yellow uniforms, etc.  Probably not what the OP is thinking of, though, because the protagonists are adults.

Comment: Any chance this could be Timeslip? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeslip

Comment: Just to clarify, I have never seen this show myself but I know it was on in the UK in the early to mid 1970's and featured children.

Comment: Can you recall if this was broadcast on the BBC or the ITV network? If you can be sure it was a BBC show that probably narrows down the number of choices.

Comment: @dominic fonde I can't be sure. At this time, changing the channel involved pushing buttons on the TV set, and I was definitely not allowed to do that. My gut feeling would be ITV, as it was similar to The Tomorrow People in terms of the show's tone.

Comment: @mikescott well that does narrow it down, there were not many sf shows on ITV as I recall. I think we can rule out Space 1999 as i can't think of any episode that fits this, meanwhile have you taken a look at The Changes? there are details here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Changes_(TV_series)

Comment: There's an episode of [The Starlost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starlost) from 1973 with a place ruled by children all dressed in yellow uniforms (with numbers on them) and they subdue the adults, if that helps. You can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4FbfOKHEgc).

Comment: @D.H. have you had the chance to take a look at Walt's link? It seems like a reasonable match - can you tell us if it's the one, or if the search continues?

Comment: @Walt Sorry, it's not that programme, but thanks for your comment.